# How can I match multiple hits between 2 delimiters?

Tags: regex, pcre

**Hi, my fellow RegEx'ers ;)**

I'm trying to match multiple Texts between every two quotes
Here's my text:

```
...random code
someArray[] =         ["Come and",
                       "get me,",
                       "or fail",
                       "trying!",
                       "Yours truly"]
random code...
```

So far, I managed to get the correct matches with **two** patterns, executed after each other:

```
(?s)someArray\[\].*?=.*?\[(.*?)\]
```

this extracts the text between the two brackets and on the result, I use this one:

```
"(.*?)"
```

This is working just fine, but I'd love to get the Texts in one regex.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `\G`. With its help, you may match `"(.*?)"` preceded by either `someArray[] = [` or previous match of `"(.*?)"` (well, strictly speaking previous match of entire regex). Then just grab first capture groups from all matches:

```
(?:(?s).*someArray\[\].*?=.*?\[|\G[^"\]]+)"(.*?)"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eBQWdU/3

How you grab the first capture groups from depends on the language you're using regex in. For example in PHP you may do something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:(?s).*someArray\[\].*?=.*?\[|\G[^"\]]+)"(.*?)"/', $input, $matches);
$array_items = $matches[1];
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/mZgU1x

Comment: Awesome, Dmitry! Unfortunately almost perfect, but it also matches too much. See Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/eBQWdU/2
The first line is matched, if there's ANY letter before the quotes

Comment: @TheFriesel: Good point. The regex should be extended by adding `.*` before `someArray`. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Just great, Dmitry! It's working perfectly now! Thx so much! Would love to rate your answer up, but i dont have enough reputation...even lost 2 reps for my question ;)